# what statistics test should i run to show that something is significantly different from 0?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have the results of a lab test for bacterial growth on agar, in my sample, most colonies grew a small amount and a couple grew a lot and a couple did not grow at all. I have to use the different lengths of the growth ring radii to show that the sample of radii is significantly different form 0.

In other words, is there a statistical test that can show that this sample is significantly different from 0, so that I can say with 99% confidence that it is the same for the population?

if it helps, the growth colony ring radii from my experiment are

- 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 14, 11, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4

radii of 14 and 11 seem to be outliers to me as well but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

With a variable that cannot be negative, even a *single positive value* is sufficient to cause us to reject a null hypothesis that the average ring size is 0 against the alternative that it's greater than 0.

That's because for the population mean ring size to be 0, *all values in the population must be exactly 0*. If even a single member of the population is non-zero, we can be certain that the average exceeds 0. If we observe even one non-zero value in our sample, the population must have at least that many non-zero values in it.

No test is necessary; you can say with certainty that the average ring size is not zero.

(It may be that more careful identification of a suitable hypothesis is needed.)

Comment: +1. The last, parenthetical statement is also important. It sounds like the OP might be wanting to project the 21% no-growth number to the population.